# Python scrape web query and put it into .csv

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Using python, I want to extract information from a website:**

1. **phone**
2. **email**
3. **website**
4. **main activity** (li element text without the div) "Computer consultancy activities".

**Issues:**

1. The code does not get the needed information every the time because sometimes the html elements are missing or varies and will give errors in python because of that:

> - sometimes the company website does not exist in html request result

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-1"><div class="col-1-text">Website:</div></td>
    <td class="col-2"><div class="col-2-text"><a href="http://www.somecompany.com" target="_blank">www.somecompany.com</a></div></td>
</tr>
```

> - sometimes the email does not exist in html request result

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-1"><div class="col-1-text">E-mail:</div></td>
    <td class="col-2"><div class="col-2-text"><a href="mailto:some@one.com">some@one.com</a></div></td>
</tr>
```

2. I am not sure how to write new line into csv without overwriting the same line over and over again in in extracted.csv. I messed up the loop and I am not sure how to fix it.
3. Thirdly, It needs to to crawl only new entries in the future (every week or so), so I think it also need to check the extracted.csv (timestamp) every time to avoid duplicate content before It will put a new line into the extracted.csv.

**HTML Code structure (example):**

```
<table class="table-info">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-1">
                <div class="col-1-text">Business name</div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-2">
                <div class="col-2-text">Company XYZ</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-1">
                <div class="col-1-text">Register code:</div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-2">
                <div class="col-2-text">112233558</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
 
 
        <tr>
            <td class="col-1">
                <div class="col-1-text">Operating address:</div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-2">
                <div class="col-2-text"><a target="googlemaps" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Some-location"
                        class="link-location">Some location strt. 233</a></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-1">
                <div class="col-1-text">Legal address</div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-2">
                <div class="col-2-text">
                    <a class="link-location" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Some-location" target="_new">Some
                        location
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-1">
                <div class="col-1-text">VAT No:</div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-2">
                <div class="col-2-text"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return getVAT(this, '12345678')">Get VAT
                        liability</a></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-1">
                <div class="col-1-text">Age:</div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-2">
                <div class="col-2-text">1 year&nbsp;3 months</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-1">
                <div class="col-1-text">Founded:</div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-2">
                <div class="col-2-text">20/09/2019</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-1">
                <div class="col-1-text">Capital:</div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-2">
                <div class="col-2-text">2000 USD</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="sep"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-1">
                <div class="col-1-text">Phone:</div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-2">
                <div class="col-2-text">123456789</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-1">
                <div class="col-1-text">E-mail:</div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-2">
                <div class="col-2-text"><a href="mailto:some@one.com">some@one.com</a></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-1"><div class="col-1-text">Website:</div></td>
            <td class="col-2"><div class="col-2-text"><a href="http://www.somecompany.com" target="_blank">www.somecompany.com</a></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="sep"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-1">
                <div class="col-1-text">Representatives:</div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-2">
                <div class="col-2-text">
                    <div class="box-message">
                        <p class="desc">To access information, please</p>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" onclick="return loginClicked(this, '#');"
                                class="btn btn-small btn-purple link-login">Log in</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="sep"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-1">
                <div class="col-1-text">
                    Main activity:
                    <span class="tip info" title=""
                        data-original-title="Activities are classified according to EMTAK 2008"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-2">
                <div class="col-2-text" id="activity_top5ffe2eab23d13">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Computer consultancy activities
                            <div class="main_activities_top_link_wrapper">
                                <a href="https://www.somesite.com/" target="_blank"
                                    onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'check', 'top_btn', 'Anonym');"
                                    class="btn btn-simple btn-open-graph">
                                    <span>Open TOP 20</span> </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
 
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
 
 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Python code:**

```
import csv
import requests
import datetime
import time
 
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
 
with open('data.csv', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    next(reader)
 
    count = 0
     
    for row in reader:
         
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
 
        url = f'https://www.somedomain.com/result?country=en&q={row[1]}'
         
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
        cookies = {'__test': '1bb6e881021f013463740eeb74840b18'}
        content = get(url, headers=headers,  cookies=cookies).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
 
        table_info = soup.select_one('.table-info')
 
        mail = table_info.select_one('.col-2 a[href^=mailto]')
        mail = mail.get('href')
        mail_clean = mail.split(':')[1]
 
        website = soup.find(text='Website:')
        website = table_info.select_one('.col-2 a[target^=_blank]')
        website = website.get('href') 
         
        collected_data = row[1], mail_clean, website, timestamp
 
        data_list = [["Regcode", "Email", "Website", "Timestamp"],collected_data]
        with open('extracted.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
            writer.writerows(data_list)
 
        print(row[1], "|", mail_clean,"|", website,"|", timestamp)
        #print("Waiting 3 seconds...")
        #time.sleep(3)
        count+=1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find or select elements from python to scrape with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65700436/find-or-select-elements-from-python-to-scrape-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: can you share a few lines of `data.csv`?

Comment: also, if you're looking to append to the file, not overwrite, change from `'w'` to `'a'`. see if that works: `with open('extracted.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have quite a bit here. NORMALLY, you should limit a SO post to 1 question and issue, but I'll work through each issue. It would be easier if you provided at least a few rows of your `data.csv`

1.

> The code does not get the needed information every the time because
> sometimes the html elements are missing or varies and will give errors
> in python because of that:

Use `if` logic to check if it's present. If it's not there, then have the variable as an empty string, null, nana, or whatever you want

You could also use the `try/except`. I like using that, however I've been told a few times that technically, shouldn't use it in that manner

I put both in there as you can see it though.

2. you want to append not overwrite, so change from `'w'` to `'a`'. Also I don't think you want to keep writing the column names, so you'd need to account for that some way. few ways you can do it.
3. Have the script load in the `extract.csv` file (if it exists, and make a list of what ever you need it to check. Then have the script check that list to see if it's repeat of what you are about to write. If it's not there, write to the file, if it is, don't write it.

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import datetime
import time
import os.path




with open('data.csv', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    next(reader)

    count = 0

    for row in reader:

        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        url = f'https://www.somedomain.com/result?country=en&q={row[1]}'

        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
        cookies = {'__test': '1bb6e881021f013463740eeb74840b18'}
        content = get(url, headers=headers,  cookies=cookies).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

        table_info = soup.select_one('.table-info')

        if table_info.select_one('.col-2 a[href^=mailto]') == None:
            mail = 'N/A'

        else:
            mail = table_info.select_one('.col-2 a[href^=mailto]')
            mail = mail.get('href')
            mail_clean = mail.split(':')[1]


        try:
            website = soup.find(text='Website:').find_next('a')['href']
        except:
            website = 'N/A'


        collected_data = row[1], mail_clean, website, timestamp

        data_list = [["Regcode", "Email", "Website", "Timestamp"],collected_data]


        if os.path.isfile('extracted.csv'):
            header_exist = True
            check_list = pd.read_csv('extracted.csv', delimiter=';')['Regcode'].tolist()
        else:
            header_exist = False
            check_list = []


        with open('extracted.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
            if header_exist == False:
                writer.writerows(data_list)
                print(row[1], "|", mail_clean,"|", website,"|", timestamp)
            else:
                if row[1] not in check_list:
                    writer.writerows([collected_data])
                    print(row[1], "|", mail_clean,"|", website,"|", timestamp)
                else:
                    print(" ** ALREADY EXIST ** ", row[1], "|", mail_clean,"|", website,"|", timestamp)


        #print("Waiting 3 seconds...")
        #time.sleep(3)
        count+=1
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried the code but i get issue with the csv. It looks like this: https://prnt.sc/wmvmve

Comment: the data.csv look like this: https://prnt.sc/wmvshg

Comment: Ok. I’ll take a look and fix tomorrow.

Comment: To my mind it has to do something how the email/website request is made. the extracted.csv have 1st row which look OK but it brokes the next row/request where the company has website in the table. First html: https://prnt.sc/wmzo7j, and second: https://prnt.sc/wmzsuy

Comment: first i forgot to have `collected_data` as a list. I fixed that. The other issue you'll have to work out o your own. Like I said, if I don't have the data.csv file (that I'm able to use the url here `content = get(url, headers=headers,  cookies=cookies).content` to get the html, I'm limited in what I can do. Also in that second screen schot, it has the website labeled as `"Homepage"`

Comment: I discovered that there is one issue in the code. It will still put duplicate row into extracted.csv except those which have website. It must check not the website in extracted.csv but the row[1] which is regcode.

Comment: Ok, There is still a line: if website not in check_list:

Comment: also, it gives error because you removed 6 lines of code: NameError: name 'header_exist' is not defined

Comment: Ok now i got different error, I am not sure what that means: `line 50
    else:
         ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level` this is reference where is lines of code:  `else: header_exist = False`

Comment: means exactly what it says. your indentation is off. any if else statements blocks need to have same indentation

Comment: Yep, that did fix the error. I removed the extracted.csv, ran the code and everything looked OK, but the second time i ran, it still adds duplicate rows into extracted.csv, it does not recognize it for some reason, also didnt print ALREADY EXIST into console, just added all the rows into extracted.csv at the end again

Comment: Is it something to do with: `if row[1] not in check_list:`

Comment: unless you share with me the data.csv file, and the actual `url = f'https://www.somedomain.com/result?country=en&q={row[1]}'` that you are using, theres not much I can do. You'll have to debug yourself. first thing I would check is that you need make sure the `row[1]` and the elements in `check_list` are the same data types

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227332/discussion-between-tuuni-and-chitown88).